Did God create without limitations?
We know that Allah is the creator of everything, and we also know in many verses and hadiths that Allah's Arsh is the greatest being. The question is, can Allah potentially create something greater than Arsh? Or is the Arsh only the limit for some of his creatures and not all creatures? Or is the Arsh already finalized and it is no longer possible for there to be a creation that in principle exceeds the Arsh?
Apologies if this question is too outrageous and ambiguous, wassalamu'alaikum.

Can you please provide evidence for your claim that Allah's 'Arsh is the greatest being?

I read it in many interpretations of Arsh and kursy. There are many articles about it on Islamic websites.
